# Submanifold such that $M-A$ is simply connected then $M$ is simply connected

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I am trying to prove the following statement

> Let $M$ be a manifold and $A$ a submanifold of codimension greater or equal to $2$. If $M-A$ is Simply connected then $M$ is simply connected.

Now I was able to see that $M$ is path connected. For the part where $\pi_1(M)=\{0\}$ is where I don't know what to do . Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure: Are your manifolds smooth?

Comment: Yes my manifolds are smooth @PrudiiArca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formalization hint. Any loop $\gamma$ in $M$ can be approximated by a differential loop $\alpha$ transversal to $A$.
Now: (i) approximation implies homotopy, and (ii) since
$\dim(\alpha)+\dim(A)<\dim M$, transversality just means
$\alpha\cap A=\varnothing$.

Two edits for the asking.

(i) One can suppose $M\subset\mathbb R^p$. Then any two maps $\gamma,\alpha:I\to M$ are homotopic in $\mathbb R^p$ by linear interpolation. Then if $\alpha$ is close enough to $\gamma$, you get that interpolation inside a tubular neighborhood $W$ of $M$ in $\mathbb R^p$, hence can retract it into $M$.

(ii) Density of transversality can be formulated in many ways, here it is enough the one that so-called “parametrized”. I think a good reference is Abraham-Robbin’s *Transversal Mappings and flows*. The formal statement is just what needed: any mapping can be approximated by a differential mapping transversal to any given submanifold.

Comment: Ah wow I was trying to do this creating the homotopy myself , I will try to think about this way thanks ! Also it's the first time I see mentioned that approximation implies homotopy, is this a good exercise or should I look it up in some reference ? (by good exercise I mean something that doesn't use a very crazy idea that I wouldn't probably come up with)

Comment: Also could you go into more detail why any loop can be approximated by a differential loop $\alpha$ transversal to $M$? We know that transversal maps are dense, but I don't see how to get the result. @Jesus RS

Comment: I’ll edit a bit my answer!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Given a closed curve $\gamma$ in $M$, problems can only occur if $\gamma$ intersects $A$, i.e., $Y:=\gamma^{-1}(A)$ is a non-empty subset of $[0,1]$. Now if we can deform $\gamma$ such that it avoids $A$, we are in $M-A$ and can contract. For the simplest case, consider an *isolated* point $t\in Y$. We want to "push" $\gamma(t)$ (i.e., continuously modify $\gamma$ in a small neighbourhood of $t$) in a direction that does not keep $\gamma(t)$ in $A$ and also not in a direction along $\gamma$ because that could "pull" other points of the curve into $A$. By the codimension condition, we have at least one "other" direction available to play with.

[image]

Comment: Okay I think I understand the idea , we just want to show that the curve will he equivalent to a curve that lies in $M-A$ and so we get our result. Just having some trouble formalizing the argument now but thanks.

Comment: First I am restricting myself to a single coordinate chart but I don't quite see how we would need the codimension greater or equal to $2$. Suppose we have $(U,\phi)$ a chart such that $A\cap U =\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{R^k}\times \{0\})$. Then in local coordinates the curve will look like $c(t)=(c_1(t),...,c_k(t),c_{k+1}(t))$, where $k$ is the dimension of $A$. Now we could consider $H(t,s):[0,1]^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$, that sends $(t,s)\rightarrow (c_1(t),...,c_k(t),c_{k+1}(t)+Ms)$, where $M=-2min_{t\in [0,1]}c_{k+1}(t)$. Again this is only locally

Comment: I don;t know if this could be doable if the curve isn't contained in a single coordinate chart.